# OneDrive OAuth 2.0 and Postman Sanity Check

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, onedrive

I am trying to generate a `OAuth Token` for `OneDrive` by using Postman. I just wanted to ask for clarification as to what the Auth URL, Access Token URL and scope would be?

I have tried it with:

**Auth URL:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

**Access Token URL:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

**Scopes:** wl.signin

However, I keep getting an error around the scope is not correct. Just for sanity check are these the correct settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm for full documentation of the possible auth flows, scopes etc.

```
auth URL: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf
token URL: https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
```

Valid scopes can be:

```
offline_access
onedrive.readonly
onedrive.readwrite
onedrive.appfolder
```

Documentation of the OneDrive API in general, including the above link, can be found here: https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm

Answer (score 0):

From the Auth/Token URLs, it looks like you're trying to use the unified consumer / work OAuth 2.0 end point for Microsoft Graph. The `wl.signin` scope isn't a valid scope for that end point. That scope is only available for the Microsoft Account (consumer only) authentication.

With those URLs, you'll want to use the `User.Read` scope, which grants you the ability to sign-in and read the signed in users basic profile. Additional scopes available on that end point are documented here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes. Since you mentioned OneDrive, you'll probably want to include `Files.ReadWrite` as one of your scopes as well, so your app can access the user's OneDrive files.