# What is the proper way to work with the OneDrive API?

Tags: c#, azure, onedrive

I want to interact with OneDrive in my WinForms application. Sadly, the Azure quick start samples do not include WinForms, just UWD.

The flow on what I have to do is consistent, namely given my `Client ID`, I have to obtain an `Authentication Code`. Given the authentication code, I can then obtain an `Access Code`, which will allow me to interact in a RESTful way with the `OneDrive` API. My plan is to have the authentication piece go in a `.Net Framework Library` and the file IO calls will go in another library that has no user interface access, as it will go in a Windows Service. I would pass the Access Token to the service.

```
AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.
```

This error corresponds to the following code fragment that I lifted from the sample .Net Core daemon quick start code.

Note: I was playing around with `Scopes` as I kept receiving scope errors and I saw one article, whose link I should have kept, which stated to use the API and default scope.

```
public bool GetRestAuthenticationToken(out string tokenAuthentication)
    {
        tokenAuthentication = null;
        try
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Authenticate.AppClientId)
                                                      .WithClientSecret(Authenticate.AppClientSecret)
                                                      .WithAuthority(new Uri(@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"))
                                                      .Build();


            string scope = $"onedrive.readwrite offline_access";
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> enumScopes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            enumScopes.Add("api://<GUID>/.default");
            //enumScopes.Add(Authenticate.Scopes[1]);
            var result = Task.Run(async () => await app.AcquireTokenForClient(enumScopes).ExecuteAsync()).Result;
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```

I believe that I have my application configured properly now on Azure, but am not 100% positive.

API Permissions:

[image: Registered App on Azure Portal Showing API Permissions]

Authentication:

- Desktop Applications: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
- Desktop Applications: https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf
- Implicit Grants: Access `tokens` & `ID tokens`
- Live SDK support (Yes)
- Default client type (Yes)

Others:

- I do have a client secret and kept note of all the Overview `GUIDs`

[Microsoft Doc 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online)

I tried several different URLs, but only the one not commented out works with the fragment above, but throws the referenced error.

```
            //string redirect_uri = @"https://www.myapp.com/auth";
            //string redirect_uri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
            string url = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";
            //string url = $"https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={appClientId}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}";
            //string url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
            //                $"client_id={Authenticate.AppClientId}&" +
            //                $"scope={scope}&" +
            //                $"response_type=token&" +
            //                $"redirect_uri={redirect_uri}";
```

The goal is the same, namely to obtain an access token that I can use with `RESTful` calls to work with files and/or directories on OneDrive, e.g.

```
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.GetAsync(...);
```

Comment: Azure does not care whether you're using Winforms or some other API. And, unsurprisingly, your question doesn't appear to include any mention of anything specific about Winforms that's causing you trouble. I've removed the Winforms-specific descriptors from the post.

Comment: I would download something like postman.  At the end of the day everything should be RESTFul APIs.  Using a tool like postman you can test the API calls quickly.

Comment: @Ron I do not see any quick start that has the name postman. If you want me to look at OneDrive API handling with RESTful APIs, I would be very happy to do that, just I have not found any example. Saying "postman" does not help. Please provide a URL.

Comment: Postman is a 3rd party software https://www.postman.com/  It also has an option to give you c# code to make certain calls.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman   Here is another StackOverflow about onedrive API.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857280/onedrive-oauth-2-0-and-postman-sanity-check

Comment: Please try to use client credential flow to get access token in postman: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement Client credentials grant type to get the access token.

Based on [MSAL initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon#msal-initialization), `Authority` is

> (**Optional**) The STS endpoint for user to authenticate. Usually
> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D) for public cloud, where
> {tenant} is the name of your tenant or your tenant Id.

We assume that your tenant is "myTenent.onmicrosoft.com", then you should set it as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenent.onmicrosoft.com` here.

I notice that you specify a scope "onedrive.readwrite" in your code. But it's not a valid permission of Microsoft Graph. The default scope of Microsoft Graph is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: What I would like to see is a RESTful API that works. The problem is that virtually all code for .Net is UWD based, whereas my application is WinForms. I am sorry that the community took out WinForms, YES WINFORMS, but that makes a huge difference. The current code that I have throws a warning that the Microsoft.Graph/Identity code is UWD and will not work. saying "myTenant" is helpful, but without code to back that up, I am not any further along.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger Do you mean that you want a WinForms sample?